# How to generate duplicate records in dataflow with different value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to generate a column based on some logic. example:

If Column1=A then Column2='A1' and If Column=A then Column2='A2'

like for one source row, I need to generate 2 rows in dataflow with different values.
for one single records from source, dataflow should populate 2 different values in another column.

how can I achieve this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> As per your ask, If `Column1=A then Column2='A1' and If Column=A then Column2='A2'` like for one source row, **I need to generate 2 rows in dataflow with different values. for one single records** from source, dataflow should populate 2 different values in column.

***To achieve Above scenario, you can follow below steps:***

1. My source dataset is a CSV file in Azure data lake gen2.`Source1` .
   [image]
2. At `DerivedColumn1` activity, we can select the **Column2** column and enter expression `concat(Column1,'2',',',Column,'1')` to generate and concat the values with comma.
   [image]
3. At `DerivedColumn2` activity, we can select the **Column2** column and enter expression `split(Column2,',')` to split this column to an Array.
   [image]
4. At `Flatten1` activity, select `Column2[]` as **Unroll by** and **Unroll root**.
   [image]

**The debug result is as follows:**
[image]

Comment: I am trying this approach but in my case, I have few rows for which I do not want to populate multiple row values. example- If I have 2 rows in source files as A and B, the in column2 I want to populate like for A--A1 and A2(in 2 rows) and for B--B1 (only single row). So If I concat the data then I can have it for only 1 source row and I cannot split as not all column2 has concat value. can you suggest anything in this issue?

Comment: Can you seperate rows for which you want two values and rows for which you want only single value?

Comment: No, I cannot as I have to us that one column to generate primary key in my table..and map it to one single database column

Comment: please add more delails what exactly your reqirements.